# How to convert html data using python

Tags: python, extract

I am looking for piece of advice as I am newbie to python.

Let's imagine that I have multiple data blocks similar to following one:

`<td>
<a href="address.com" title=title">some title</a>
<br />
aaa<br />
bbb<br />
ccc</td>`

Sometimes number of br differs and is not constant for all blocks.

My purpose is to extract data from inside td block to file however I stuck here.

Is it regular expression here the best approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: BeautifulSoup may suit your need, if you're dealing with lots of these data blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the HTML with a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup (`pip install beautifulsoup4`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td> <a href="address.com" title=title">some title</a> <br /> aaa<br /> bbb<br /> ccc</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    print(td.get_text())
```

And the result:

```
 some title  aaa bbb ccc
```